# using a regular expression on a variable?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Say I have this for example:

```
$(function() {

    var seconds = 142.097019375;

    seconds = seconds.replace(/\.[0-9]*/, '');

    alert(seconds); 

});
```

This wont work, but if seconds was `$('.seconds').html();` it would replace it, is there anyway to perform a regex on a jquery variable as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the Number object doesn't have a `.replace` function.

Use `seconds = seconds.toString().replace(/\.[0-9]*/, '');`

Answer (score 6):

If your variable is a number and you're really trying to extract just the integer part, then you'll want to use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
var int_part = seconds > 0 ? Math.floor(seconds) : Math.ceil(seconds);
```

Comment: @Jason: And that's why people try to use regular expressions when other parsing methods are more appropriate.

Comment: and I'll be here on SO fighting the good fight. Thanks for the edit, that radix was killing you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't call [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2) (specifically, [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) on [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)s. Try converting the `Number` to a `String` first:

```
seconds = (seconds + "").replace(/\.[0-9]*/, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are merely trying to drop the decimals from a number, this is not a good use of regular expressions.

Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), like:

```
parseInt(seconds, 10);
```

See that it does the same thing - http://jsfiddle.net/bzAGe/

Comment: Thanks for that, why is it a horrible use of a regular expression though?

Comment: Simply put, overkill. Especially when `seconds` is already a number. What's more intuitive to drop decimal places - change and number to a string and use a regular expression or make the number an int?

Comment: @BrunoLM, note that `parseFloat()` will not drop the decimal places. Unless you are suggesting to `parseFloat(string)`, then `parseInt(float)`.

Answer (score 1):

Force it to a string first:

```
$(function() {

    var seconds = "" + 142.097019375;

    seconds = seconds.replace(/\.[0-9]*/, '');

    alert(seconds); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the integer part of this var? [**Use Math.floor**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp). There are other method that you might want to know, [look a Math object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp).

**Definition and Usage**

> The floor() method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer, and returns the result.

**Syntax**

```
Math.floor(x)

Parameter     Description
x             Required. A number
```

---

#### Using regex

`replace` is a `String` method, you can convert it to a string before performing the replace

```
(seconds.toString()).replace()
```

or declare seconds as a string

```
var seconds = "value";
```

[Javascript String object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

- [replace()](http://replace%28%29%20%09Searches%20for%20a%20match%20between%20a%20substring%20%28or%20regular%20expression%29%20and%20a%20string,%20and%20replaces%20the%20matched%20substring%20with%20a%20new%20substring)   Searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring

**Syntax**

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)

Parameter         Description
regexp/substr     Required. A substring or a regular expression.
newstring         Required. The string to replace the found value in parameter 1
```